# Why does a tokio thread wait for a blocking thread before continuing?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Why does my blocking thread output twice before the other thread outputs once? I'd like to be able to spawn off tasks to run in the background (immediately) but not wait for them to complete before the main code continues. Is there an easy way to do this with `tokio`?

Code:

```rust
use std::{thread, time};
use chrono;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Starting up");
    tokio::spawn(blocking_thread()).await.unwrap();
    Ok(())
}

async fn blocking_thread() {
    for i in 1..5 {
        println!("{} Blocking thread {}", chrono::offset::Utc::now(), i);
        tokio::spawn(other_thread(i));
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100)); //In my real code this is a blocking syscall
    }
}

async fn other_thread(i: u8) {
    println!("{} Other thread {}", chrono::offset::Utc::now(), i);
}
```

Output:

```
Starting up
2022-01-21 09:03:36.662248332 UTC Blocking thread 1
2022-01-21 09:03:36.762375086 UTC Blocking thread 2
2022-01-21 09:03:36.762617994 UTC Other thread 1
2022-01-21 09:03:36.862634161 UTC Blocking thread 3
2022-01-21 09:03:36.862913141 UTC Other thread 2
2022-01-21 09:03:36.963055279 UTC Blocking thread 4
2022-01-21 09:03:36.963383710 UTC Other thread 3
2022-01-21 09:03:37.063496911 UTC Other thread 4
```

Comment: `spawn` is for non-blocking futures. Try `spawn_blocking`.

Comment: Why the `blocking_thread` has to be `async` at all? You don't `await` anything inside it, so it probably should just be called synchronously?

Comment: @Cerberus because I need to do other things while `blocking_thread` is running. Am I misunderstanding how `async` works? I want to spawn a few worker threads, one of which always blocks on a syscall (as `blocking_thread` here) and others which handle the results produced by the `blocking_thread`.

Comment: Well, if you want to spawn threads, why don't you do it explicitly, without relying on the async runtime? What's that you're using that expects you to use `async`?

Comment: Tokio is primarily designed to work with non-blocking system calls. If you need a blocking system call and can't implement the same the task with a non-blocking call, see https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/index.html#cpu-bound-tasks-and-blocking-code. However unless you are using tokio for something else, rayon may be a more appropriate tool.

Comment: Funnily enough, it works if you don't use `spawn` when calling `blocking_thread`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=60b817b88bf1ac327a7051265c653c71)

Comment: Il also works if you wrap the blocking system call in a `spawn_blocking`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3fcda15406e5a37af5c97b9d1cd120ca)

Comment: @Cerberus Thanks, that's what I was missing. Coming to Rust from Java I was trying to use Tokio like a ThreadPoolExecutor, which it isn't. Would you like to submit that as an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 5):

> Why does my blocking thread output twice before the other thread
> outputs once

Use `tokio::time::sleep` for sleeping in the `blocking_thread`. Because thread::sleep will not yield execution to the main tokio executer.

> I'd like to be able to spawn off tasks to run in the background
> (immediately) but not wait for them to complete before the main code
> continues.

You are waiting on `tokio::spawn(blocking_thread()).await.unwrap();` line for the thread to complete. Don't `await` if you want to continue in the main.

Comment: Thanks, I added a clarification that the `thread::sleep` represents a blocking syscall in the real code.

Comment: If you add `tokio::task::yield_now().await;` before the blocking code, it will run the thread before the blocking code. I don't know why it is this way. As far as I understand, the execution should be yielded to the executor for the thread to be really spawned.