# long tasks inside actix_rt::spawn blocking main thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, celery, actix-web

I am using actix web with this crate https://github.com/rusty-celery/rusty-celery for celery background tasks and scheduling

I though that sending the tasks to separate thread would not block the main thread unless am doing something wrong

from within my main function am creating celery task consumer as

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
 //
// ... app state and other things
//
  let app_celery = celery::app!(
        broker = RedisBroker { std::env::var("REDIS_URL").unwrap() },
        tasks = [
             some_task // this is a task added to consumer
                ],
        task_routes = [
            "*" => QUEUE_NAME,
        ],
    )
    .await
    .unwrap();

    let app_celery_clone: Arc<Mutex<Arc<Celery>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(app_celery.clone()));

    actix_rt::spawn({
        let app_celery_clone = app_celery_clone.clone();
        async move {
            let my_app = app_celery_clone.lock().await;
            my_app.consume().await.unwrap();
        }
    });

    actix_rt::spawn({
        async move {
            beat_runner(QUEUE_NAME).await;
        }
    });
   
    HttpServer::new(move || {
         App::new()
          //... more config
      }).bind(server_addr)?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

and my beat consumer as

```rust
pub async fn beat_runner(queue_name: &str) {
    let mut beat = celery::beat!(
        broker = RedisBroker { std::env::var("REDIS_URL").unwrap() },
        tasks = [
            "renew_token" => {
                get_new_token,
                schedule = DeltaSchedule::new(Duration::from_secs(60 * 60)),
                args = ()
            },
        ],
        task_routes = [
            "*" => queue_name,
        ],
    )
    .await
    .unwrap();

    beat.start().await.unwrap();
}
```

```rust
#[celery::task]
pub async fn some_task(arg_1:i32) -> TaskResult<()> {
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(60));
    Ok(())
    }
```

I am then sending a task from one of my endpoint as

```rust
app_state.celery_tasks
            .send_task(some_task::new(arg_1))
            .await?;
```

the task is sent and is being consumed but there is some issue...

for the 60 seconds that the task is running there is no http request that can be processes by the application I though that `actix_rt::spawn` was supposed to be a way to create some tasks to run in different thread but for some reason that blocks my main thead yet I wanted the consumer of the tasks to be in different thread

could there be something am doing wrong or that the `actix_rt::spawn`  is failing to work as intended in this case

Comment: This is kind of related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70798841/6274355 but you would use [actix's `sleep`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/rt/time/fn.sleep.html) instead of tokio's (which are actually the same, just different namespace). Never block in a cooperative threadpool like actix/tokio. If you need to run blocking code, use [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/rt/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html).